# How to delete all items from UICollectionView on click of a button

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview

I want all items in the UICollectionView to be deleted when I click a button. When the button is clicked, an alert message is popped. On hitting "ok", the items in the collection view should be deleted. I have used the following code so far:

```
NSArray *selectedItemsIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
[self deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths];
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:selectedItemsIndexPaths];

-(void)deleteItemsFromDataSourceAtIndexPaths:(NSArray  *)itemPaths
{
    NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    for (NSIndexPath *itemPath  in itemPaths) {
        [indexSet addIndex:itemPath.row];
    }
    [self.collectionViewData removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
}
```

The first three lines of code are within "clickedButtonAtIndex" of alert view.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of clearing out a UICollectionVew is to simply clear the data source and then reload the collection view.

So if your data source was an array:

```
self.dataArray = nil;
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Boom, you're cleared out.